# Ethernet inet6 issue

Tags: ubuntu, ethernet, ipv6

I have a selfhosting server working on Ubuntu 21.10, I'm using Cloudflare service and everything was working good until suddenly my eth0 adapter won't resolve an IPV6 address.
this weird issue start taking in place when the server finish booting up, while the server is starting up the results for ifconfig eth0 command as below

```
    eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            inet 192.168.1.34  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
            inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fee7:4630  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
            inet6 2a01:9700:104c:1300:dea6:XXX:fXXX:4630  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
            ether dc:a6:32:e7:46:30  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 659  bytes 117213 (117.2 KB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 2  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 414  bytes 92200 (92.2 KB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

but after finishing up the booting the result become this

```
    eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            inet 192.168.1.34  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
            ether dc:a6:32:e7:46:30  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 2606  bytes 1552064 (1.5 MB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 3  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 1010  bytes 155231 (155.2 KB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I'm unable to access my selfhosting sites at all, or ping -6 any website

any recommendations? or solution?
My Network manager conf

[main]
dns=default
plugins=keyfile
autoconnect-retries-default=0
rc-manager=file

[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=type:bridge;type:tun;type:veth

[logging]
backend=journal

Comment: What does the system log show happening with the Ethernet interface during boot until the moment IPv6 disappears? Try `grep eth0 /var/log/syslog` or `dmesg | grep eth0`. Please edit your question and add the result formatted as code so it stays readable.

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt
I tried to paste them her but due to the long log I added them to this link
https://pastebin.com/KuMKNkzg

Comment: It seems you are using Network Manager. Please edit your question to include your Network Manager configuration. Also there are a lot of `eth0: renamed from vethxxx` messages. Are you running docker on that server?

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt , Yes I use Docker on that server. Did you found any issue regarding to log?

Comment: I found a lot of puzzling messages like "eth0: renamed from veth..." and activating and deactivating links which would definitely indicate a problem if I saw them on one of my own systems, but a cursory search of the web seems to show they are normal with Docker. I'm not familiar with Docker's syslog footprint so I cannot judge if any of them are out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is solved, after digging deeper I found the following:
I used the following command
`nmcli connection show`
and it showed that the ethernet named as "Supervisor eth0"
which is related to Homeassistant container.
then I used this command

```
nmcli connection modify "Supervisor eth0" ipv6.method "auto"



nmcli connection up "Supervisor eth0"



ifconfig eth0
```

the eth0 now have an ipv6 address and I could access my selfhosting websites.
I rebooted the server and the issue appeared again.
I think the issue is related to the new Homeassistant update (maybe).
so I created a script to run as cron job to repeat these commands until fixing the issue.
thanks @TilmanSchmidt for inspiration.

Comment: Nice one! So a Docker container is able to kill IPv6 support on its host. Good to know.